# Javascript add days to a existing calendar object off by one month

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to read a date from a Calendar object and add a specific amount of days to it (i.e. 7)

Here is the code that I have:

```
var daysFromBeginDate = parseInt($("#policyDuration").val()) * 7
alert(daysFromBeginDate)
var beginDate = new Date("2015-04-24");
alert(beginDate)
var endDate = new Date("2015-05-08");
alert(beginDate.getDate() + daysFromBeginDate)
endDate.setDate(new Date(beginDate.getDate() + daysFromBeginDate));
alert(endDate.toString())
```

and I am getting `Sun May 31 2015 17:00:000 GMT` as my answer. It should be that with one less month, where is the extra month getting added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript using the below call, I found out that the month argument counts starting from zero.

```
new Date(2015, 3, 1);  // that's the 1st April 2015!
```

And what is causing the issue is the below code snippet in your code:-

```
endDate.getMonth() + 1
```

That is possibly the reason for your issue..

EDIT:
if the below code

```
var endDate = new Date("2015-05-08");
```

is changed to

```
var endDate = new Date();
```

you will get correct output..

it is because setDate sets the day of the month and April has only 30 days so it is rolled over and you get it as May and you get 31 because 24+7 is 31..

Comment: You answer is incorrect, I edited out that code as it is extraneous

Comment: @ChrisStewart I ran your code assuming daysFromBeginDate  is 7, I get Fri May 01 2015 as output.. Its correct April as 30days.. if you remove _var endDate = new Date("2015-05-08");_ and change it to _var endDate = new Date();_

Comment: @ChrisStewart it is because setDate sets the day of the month and April has only 30 days so it is rolled over and you get it as May and you get 31 because 24+7 is 31...